# mongodump from rasberry OS

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to create a mongodump of my atlas database, but I get the following error:

> error parsing command line options: error parsing uri (mongodb+srv://blablabla:123@blablabla.blabla.blala.mongodb.net/DATABASENAME): scheme must be "mongodb"
>
> try 'mongodump --help' for more information

Any idea, I am trying to automate my backups using a bash script.

I tried to change the url from `mongodb+srv` to `mongodb` but nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an old version of mongodump that doesn't recognize mongodb+srv URIs. Upgrade mongodump or use a non-SRV URI.

Comment: apparently apt on Raspberry Install an old versión of mongo-tools. Thanks you so much